$H(x)$ approximates $\pi(x)$ pretty well. But what are the drawbacks, when compared with Riemann's $R(x)$?
I'm aware of the Gram series which is equivalent to $R(x)$  (Riemann prime counting function):
$$ R(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}li(x^{1/n}). $$
Over the interval $x=2$ to $x=10^4$ the average difference between $R(x)$ and $\pi(x)$ (prime counting function) is accurately measured to be $<3/2$.
From my understanding $R(x)$ is an incredibly precise approximation of $\pi(x)$ especially for say $x\le 10^4$. I wondered if it was possible to re-create a function with comparable average difference and without using the Möbius function especially.
I tried to provide an attempt and find a satisfactory function like I described above. The best I could obtain is to start with
$$ f(x)= -\sum_{n=2}^x \frac{1-e^{2/\log n}}{1+e^{2/\log n}}   $$
and take $$J(x):= f(x)-1/2f(x^{1/2}) $$
which I ran a script on against $\pi(x)$ to obtain an average difference for $x\le 10^4$ of $<1.95$. Then, I took
$H(x)=J(x)+1/3f(x^{1/3})-1/4f(x^{1/4})$ obtaining average difference $<1.45$ which is below the threshold of $3/2.$ This method avoids $li(x)$, $\mu(x)$, and $\zeta(x)$.

So it's pretty clear that $H(x)$ is a good approximation to $\pi(x)$ over the stated interval. What are the drawbacks of $H(x)$ when compared to $R(x)$? Why should I not use $H(x)$ over $R(x)$?


When $z$ is small, there is
$$
e^z=1+z+O(z^2),
$$
so we have
$$
{e^z-1\over e^z+1}={z+O(z^2)\over2+O(z)}=\frac z2+O(z^2).
$$
This indicates that your $f(x)$ (plug in $z=2/\log n$) is
$$
f(x)\approx\sum_{n=2}^x{1\over\log n}\approx\int_2^x{\mathrm dt\over\log t}=\operatorname{li}(x).
$$
If you analyze the function $e^z-1\over e^z+1$ more carefully, you will find that the difference between $f(x)$ and $\operatorname{li}(x)$ grows like $x/\log^2x$.
